# Using SCI_SEARCHINTARGET in Qscintilla/PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, scintilla, qscintilla

I'm trying to search for the position of a string in a Qscintilla window.

Here's a piece of (runnable) mock code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, Qsci

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Qsci.QsciScintilla()
window.show()

# Search in target for string
text = "Hello world"
window.setText(text)
messenger = window.SendScintilla
messenger(window.SCI_SETTARGETSTART, 0)
messenger(window.SCI_SETTARGETEND, len(text))
pos = messenger(window.SCI_SEARCHINTARGET, len(text), "world")
print(pos);

app.exec_()
```

It searches for the string `"world"` in a text editor window currently holding the string `"Hello world"`. However the search returns `-1` (failed to find string), when the string clearly exists in the text editor window.

What might the problem be?

Comment: This might help: http://qscintilla.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SEARCHINTARGET: The `length` parameter is the length of the text you're searching for, not of the text you're searching in.

This will get you what you want:

```
pos = messenger(window.SCI_SEARCHINTARGET, len("world"), "world")
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't pick up on that!